# Why such trigger doesn't work?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables: `Ticket` and `Cancel`(with canceled tickets).

I created a trigger so that when a ticket is added to the `Cancel` table, it becomes free in the `Ticket` table (`Client_id` sets `NULL`).

But there must be one additional option:

If a ticket is added to the `Cancel` table,  and the ticket is free (`Client_id` is already `NULL` in the `Ticket` table) then it shouldn't be added to the `Cancel` table or cause an error.

The trigger below sets free ticket if it was bought, when adding to table `Cancel`, but it still adds ticket to table `Cancel` even if the ticket is free. I guess I should add some constraint or something like that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CANCEL_TICKET
      AFTER INSERT ON CANCEL
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
        UPDATE TICKET
          SET TICKET.CLIENT_ID = NULL
        WHERE TICKET.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID and TICKET.TICKET_ID IS NOT NULL;
      END;
```

Comment: The update from the triger is fired "AFTER INSERT ON CANCEL"

Answer (score 0):

You can use before insert in rise an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TUTOR_BLOCK
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Cancel
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    rowsCount INTEGER;
BEGIN
   <Add select statement to check if the ticket is free>
   IF rowsCount > 0
THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'The ticket is free');
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE
     UPDATE TICKET
      SET TICKET.CLIENT_ID = NULL
    WHERE TICKET.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID and TICKET.TICKET_ID IS NOT NULL;
END IF;
END;
```

Edit:
To assign value to `rowsCount` you can use the `select into` clause:
Something like

```
select count(*) into rowsCount from my_table where...
```

In other cases you can replace the count(*) with a column or other exprssion along with the variable type.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm

Comment: useful advice, but have some questions: I haven't use variables yet so I don't know what value to initialize variable rowsCOUNT. And instead of "<Add select statement to check if the ticket is free>" I should add some CHECK statement? but CHECK doesn't support SELECT statement. I have such select statement to check if the ticket is free: SELECT t.CLIENT_ID from TICKET t WHERE t.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID AND t.TICKET_ID IS NOT NULL

Comment: how to check if ticket is free? i know what select statement, but what to use to check it?

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, "check statement if ticket is true" is counting free tickets with such id? And what does rollback in this case? I understand functionality of rollback, but what happens without this statement in this case?

Comment: You can omit the rollback in this case.